# How to get the row of a ButtonWidget in a QTableWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtableview

I'm trying to dynamically fill a QTableWidget (table_proj).

It works so far that the Table is filled and it looks right.
The Code for the items in the Table:

```
for row in range(nb_row):
   for col in range(nb_col):
       item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(data[row][col]))
       self.table_proj.setItem(row, 0, item)
       self.table_proj.setCellWidget(row, 1, EditButtonWidget())
```

Where the nb_col is always two, and the nb_row is the len(data). Data is the dictionary that gets all the information.

The result looks like:

[image: QTableWidget]

The Code for the EditButton's looks like:

```
class EditButtonWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(EditButtonWidget,self).__init__(parent)

        ###

        self.dw = DockWidget()

        ###Layout###

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)

        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.layout.setSpacing(0)

        self.b1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        self.b1.setText('Webseite')
        self.b1.clicked.connect(self.doButtonB1)


        self.b2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        self.b2.setText('Link kopieren')
        self.b2.clicked.connect(self.doButtonB2)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.b1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.b2)


        self.setLayout(self.layout)


    def doButtonB1(self):

        row = self.dw.table_proj.currentRow()
        print(row)
        

    def doButtonB2(self):
        
        pass
```

My problem is, that when I click on the Button "Webseite" it doesn't give me the correct row, but instead i just receive -1.

So if someone could give me a hint, where my mistake is, that would be great.

Comment: Your code is not very clear. You are adding `EditButtonWidget` widgets to a tablewidget, but then in `doButtonB1` you're referring to `self.dw`, which we don't know what is. Please edit your question and provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (emphasis on *reproducible*).

Comment: here is your current hierarchy： top level DockWidget -> top level QTableWidget (table_proj) -> second level, table cell, EditButtonWidget -> third level, widgets inside a cell, EditButtonWidget.dw = DockWidget() -> fourth level, table inside third level dw. And the EditButtonWidget.doButtonB1(self) tries to get the currentRow of fourth level table_proj, which is still invisible. that fourth level table_proj has currentRow of -1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make the row a member of the `EditButtonWidget` class as suggested on the Qt forum [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/101092/qtablewidget-get-cell-index-from-cell-widget).

For example:

```
class EditButtonWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    
    def __init__(self, row, parent=None):
        super(EditButtonWidget,self).__init__(parent)

        self.row = row

        ### etc ...

    def doButtonB1(self):
        print(self.row)
```

and

```
for row in range(nb_row):
   for col in range(nb_col):
       item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(data[row][col]))
       self.table_proj.setItem(row, 0, item)
       self.table_proj.setCellWidget(row, 1, EditButtonWidget(row))
```

This might not work if you allow users to insert/delete/move rows. In that case you probably need to use `indexAt` as in the qt forum post or pass more information (in your case the website url) to the `EditButtonWidget`.